# Python File find and Join

Tags: python, file, path

So I am looking to combine a bunch of files in one file.

I have started by searching for all files begining with "abcde" as I have files like abcde1.txt, abcde2.txt etc etc but I can't seem to open the file as I get this error

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'abcde1.txt'
```

I've tried various `os.path.join(myPath.fileName)` things but can't seem to get it to work.

```
import os

myPath = "C:/xx/xx/xx/xx/xx/directory"
fileNameList = os.listdir(myPath)

for fileName in fileNameList:
    if fileName.lower().startswith("abcde"):
        with open(fileName, "r") as abcdeList:
            print next()
```

any ideas?

Comment: `open(os.path.join(myPath, fileName), 'r')`.

Comment: `print next()` does nothing useful; perhaps you wanted `print next(abcdeList)` instead?

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the answer. first suggestion worked!